# How do I get the value of mData in Data Tables for a specific cell using the Data Tables API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am initialising a Data Tables table with preset JSON data. I use mData to match the cell values to the columns. I want to get mData in Data tables for a specific cell when I click on any cell. Is there a way to get the mData value using the Data Tables API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the values in the DataTable, there is no need to use `mData`.

You should try an approach like this

```
$(".datatable tbody td").click(function () {
    var position = otable.fnGetPosition(this);
    var data = oTable.fnGetData(position[0]);
    //get the data of the cell
});
```

Comment: I need to know the exact column, not the data inside it. fnGetPosition doesn't help as the column positions have been rearranged and no longer correspond to the original data.

Comment: You should have specified that :) And how it is arranged now ?

Answer (score 0):

I hacked around it by setting the sClass value to match the mData value and then got that value by using standard JQuery :)